# view client browsing history

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, firefox, web

Right now My company is on Google's Blacklist somewhere someone in my company is spamming google.  I would like to view the Browsing History on my clients computers to try to find out where it is coming from.
Does anyone know an easy way to do this?  Is there a WMI object that can help me.  I would like to write a vbscript that can take a computer name and return their Browsing History.

All the computers are in a single active directory domain.
Most computers are using IE7, some are using 8 and some are using Firefox.

Is this possible?

Comment: How is analyzing their browsing history going to help you track down the source of spam? What you should be looking at is outgoing email and SMTP traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the folder where the IE History is located, either on a local hard drive or redirected to a network folder, you can use Pasco to extract the history in a readable form:

http://www.securityfocus.com/infocus/1827

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no. There's no way to obtain the browsing history using a WMI object, particularly as your looking at both IE and firefox here. You could try collecting their temporary internet files using admin shares, but there's nothing to stop them clearing this.

Your best bet is to look at doing some logging at your gateway. How do your clients access the internet, do you have a proxy, do they go straight through a NAT router, do you use ISA server or some equivalent? Look at this device and see if you can enable some sort of traffic logging with what you already have. If not you may need to look at some third party service.

Comment: So, even with a group policy stoping them from clearing the browsing history, there is not any way to view that history?

Comment: As mentioned by greg, you should be able to access the history via the file system and do something with that, but you will have to get it for both IE and firefox, and it i'll take some work to collate it.